# Convert byte of slice without copy

Tags: go

How to convert a slice of bytes to `[]uint16` and reverse without allocation new `uint16` slice. This question focused on performance and memory consumption

Comment: Im currentlu using. But I don't know is it correct:
func EncodeUint16(d []byte) []uint16 {
 return *(*[]uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(&d))
}

func EncodeToByteSl(d []uint16) []byte {
 return *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&d))
}

Answer (score 0):

Consider that [converting = copying](https://twitter.com/beyang/status/502287884942991360?lang=en), except for two special cases: `m:=map[string]int{};m[string(bytes))` has no allocation, similarly with append.

[Using unsafe.Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25409018/6309) seems the current workaround (as its name suggests, "unsafe")

```
u16 := *(*uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(&byte_array[4]))
```

There is a [proposal to use `unsafe.Slice` instead](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19367).
There is also the (rejected for now) [proposal golang/go issue 13656](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13656#issuecomment-301829361)

> The problem is having to write `(*[C]T)(unsafe.Pointer(v))[:n:n]`, for some C, T, v, and n.
>
> A simpler way to write that entire expression would be ideal.
>
> ```
> var s []byte = C.AsSlice((*byte)(ptr), n)
> ```